# Convert base64 to file type in React cropper js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, npm

I have created crop functionality using react cropper js. I need to send image as a file type. I'm able to get base64 string for cropped image. When i submit that cropped image need to be send to as a file type. Here i have included my code for crop function. How to send cropped area image as file?

Here is my code,

```
var React  = require('react');
var Cropper = require('react-cropper').default;

var MyProfileEdit = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
            open:false,
            src:"",
            cropResult: null
        }
    },
    onChange:function(e){
        var self = this;
        $("#photo").val('');
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    self.setState({
                        open:true,
                        src: reader.result
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#photo").one('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            readURL(self);
        });
    },
    cropImage:function(){
        if (typeof this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas() === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            open:false,
            cropResult: this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL()
        });
    },
    cancelCrop: function() {
        this.setState({
            open:false,
            src:"",
            cropResult:null
        });
    },
    crop:function(){
        if (typeof this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas() === 'undefined') {
          return;
        }
        this.setState({
          cropResult: this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL()
        });
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="view-container">
                <div className="scroll-content has-header">
                    <form className="edit-profile">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="profile-photo">
                                <div className="profile-photo-upload">
                                    <div className="img-preview" style={{ width: '100%', height: 120 }}>
                                        <img src="img/photo.png" width="120" alt="Photo" />
                                    </div>
                                    <span className="upload-icon">
                                        <input type="file" id="photo" onClick={this.onChange} />
                                        <input type="text" name="ptyPhoto" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className={"profile-popup "+(this.state.open ? "active" : "inactive")}>
                    <div className="crop-area">
                        <Cropper
                            style={{ height: 280, width: '100%' }}
                            preview=".img-preview"
                            aspectRatio={1 / 1}
                            guides={false}
                            src={this.state.src}
                            ref="cropper"
                            crop={this.crop} />

                        <div className="row-col">
                            <div className="col"><button className="button button-red" onClick={this.cropImage}>Crop</button></div>
                            <div className="col"><button className="button button-red" onClick={this.cancelCrop}>Cancel</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = MyProfileEdit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Blob from base64 and upload it using XMLHttpRequest.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
xhr.send(blob);
```

See here about base64 to blob conversion: [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)